# Where is the gas generator on the RS-68?

Tags: engines, power-cycle, rs-68

Wikipedia notes that the RS-68 uses a gas generator cycle. I've already seen a couple of photos of the RS-68 and I do not see any gas generator exhaust pipe or a pipe leading into the nozzle. So where is the gas generator on the RS-68, and where does this exhaust go?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's physically mounted between the turbopumps.

[image]

Its exhaust passes through the turbines and then overboard.

[image]

Source: [Propulsion for the 21st Century - RS68](https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.rocket-propulsion.info%2Fresources%2Farticles%2FPropulsionForThe21stCentury-RS-68.pdf&psig=AOvVaw3L9D9pLriiE0xcav0zyR8M&ust=1651935580256000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CA0QjhxqFwoTCMDM0N2Ry_cCFQAAAAAdAAAAABAS)

Comment: To me it looks like the GG exhaust is pumped overboard and used for roll control. Is that correct?

Comment: @fasterthanlight after it passes through the turbines, yeah. So I'd say the *turbine exhausts* are routed overboard and used for roll control.

Comment: I am assuming that this explains the two holes in the boattail of the Delta IV.

Comment: @fasterthanlight  I think so https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/cb/Delta_342_CBC_delivery.jpg